# auto complete search and search button

Tags: search, autocomplete

I am using search with auto complete that initiates search as soon as the user clicks a suggestion (list of existing movie titles). should i include a search icon next to the search box, basically to simulate search action (refreshes results). Or not?

Comment: Wait. So is there a visible search field, and the user is clicking a tag? Let's see a mock of your efforts so we can see visual context and constraints. This will make the question more precise, and the answers more useful: to you, and to future users of the site.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to accompany search box with a magnifying-glass icon and it’s important to display full open-text field. The best is if you provide a search button for the search box. It helps people recognize that there’s an additional step to trigger the search action — even if they decide to do this by pressing Enter. Size the submit button appropriately so that users don’t have to point the mouse very precisely. A larger clickable area makes it easier to spot and to click. Let users submit the search using the Enter and by clicking the icon. Many users still have the habit of clicking an actual button to submit the search.